# Concatenating large pandas dataframes produces MemoryError

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, out-of-memory, concatenation

I have used the following code for splitting a pandas dataframe column into multiple columns:

`df = pd.concat([df.X.apply(pd.Series).rename(columns="X{}".format), df.Y], axis=1)`

Its showing a memory error:

> stacked = np.empty(shape, dtype=dtype)
>   MemoryError

Comment: How big is your dataframe? Each chained operation creates copies in memory.

Answer (score 1):

`apply(pd.Series)` can be slow and expensive, so I'd recommend something more efficient using `tolist` and a `DataFrame` constructor call. You can also perform the rename on the *just* the columns, so you don't unnecessarily create a new copy of the dataframe.

```
y = df['Y']
df = pd.DataFrame(df.X.tolist(), index=df.index)
df.columns = list(map("X{}".format, df.columns))
df['Y'] = y
```

In place assignment as opposed to `pd.concat` which returns *yet another copy* should be even faster.